# Communication between Java project and Flash project

Tags: java, swing, actionscript-3, flash, communication

I have developed a chatting and video calling Java desktop application in Swing and core Java. Chatting works fine. For video and audio I am using Red5 server so I have created a Red5 application and client is in Flash. This Flash application (MXML file in ActionScript) is opening in web browser. I have used Flash Builder for creating the Flash app.

1. How can I run this Flash output (which is `.swf`) in Swing (not in browser) dynamically?
2. How can I get my Java application to communicate with Flash application (MXML file which is in Action script) at code level? I have to pass some arguments from one client to another through Java by communicating ActionScript file.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `External Interface` if target is Flash Player

For more info please see [External Interface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html).

AS3 code is like so,

```
   ExternalInterface.addCallback("yourJavaFunction", yourAS3Function);
   fscommand("someMessage to Java container from AS3");
```

Comment: My target is to play the output on swings not in browser.and I want to communicate java with action script not with html and actionscript..

Comment: ExternalInterface is not limited to browser. See Edit.